# How to update react state in useState hook?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-state

I am trying to set the error message in the state. I am using react hooks for storing error message. I don't know but it is not updating.

Here is my code,

```
const [code, setCode] = useState("");
const [codeError, setCodeError] = useState("");


.catch((error) => {
    console.log("code error", error.message, typeof error.message);
    setCodeError(error.message);
    setCode("");
    setProcessing(false);
  });
```

This is not updating the state. But it is logging the error with a type of string.

I even tried to check if the state updated using useEffect hook but it is not even logging in the useEffect hook.

Comment: I tried logging codeError in the useEffect hook

Comment: `useEffect(() => {
    console.log("code-error", codeError);
  }, [codeError]);`

Comment: The output of console.log in catch block is `Invalid verification code provided, please try again. string` and in useEffect it is an empty string.

Comment: I can't reproduce an example but I have created a gist https://gist.github.com/angelo1104/a12fee03fafb779a503073c3b7bb4aca

Comment: @AjeetShah removing those lines did solved the problem but now the problem is I want to clear the code everytime there is an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how you can do this ->

> I want to clear the code everytime there is an error.

```
useEffect(() => {
  if (codeError && code) {
    setCode("")
  }
}, [codeError])
```

Answer (score 0):

The code is correct so I would assume you are not checking the value after setting the data.

It would be better if you put the whole component here or on any code hosting site.